# Creating C# COM interface from c++ Header File: Pointers to Structures

Tags: c#, c++, com, marshalling

I am trying to create the C# COM interface for the given C++ COM interface below, but I am having troubles.

### C++ COM Interface (Working)

```
typedef struct _cmd_t
{
    int kmdf_drv_ver;
    int kmdf_drv_buildtime;
    // more, but omitted...
}cmd_t, *pCmd_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" { 
#endif 

{   
    STDMETHOD(GetCommands) (THIS_ 
        pCmd_t pCmd
    ) PURE; 

    STDMETHOD(SetCommands) (THIS_ 
        pCmd_t pCmd
    ) PURE;
}; 
#ifdef __cplusplus 
} 
#endif
```

### C# COM Interface (Not working)

```
[ComImport, Guid("574358C5-E59D-45b2-8976-0BA03D81EC07")]
public interface IRaw
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetCommands(IntPtr pCmd);

    [PreserveSigAttribute]
    int SetCommands(IntPtr pCmd);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct IRawCmd
{
    public int kmdf_drv_ver;
    public int kmdf_drv_buildtime;
    // more, but ommited
}
```

When I call GetCommands, the COM service is supposed to populate the structure with values. However, it seems that with the following code, the structure is left untouched.

```
var commands = new IRawCmd();
var pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(commands));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(commands, pointer, false);

_deviceFilterRaw.GetCommands(pointer);

var result = Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof (IRawCmd));
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using ref parameters in my C# interface?

Comment: Can you try using: var pointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(commands)); ?

Comment: I just tried it and had same result.

Comment: Is your dll registered or is the guid the correct one?

Comment: Yes. This header file works as expected in a sample C++ project I have. It is the C# interface.

Comment: If you apply this attribute [ComImport, Guid("574358C5-E59D-45b2-8976-0BA03D81EC07",InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)] ?

Comment: WORKED!!!!!!!!!!   ADD AS ANSWER AND I WILL ACCEPT!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply this attribute to the interface `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.Inter‌​faceIsIUnknown)` :

```
[ComImport, Guid("574358C5-E59D-45b2-8976-0BA03D81EC07",InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.Inter‌​faceIsIUnknown)]
```

[ComInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz0x1301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)